# Implementing the custom permissions from the Django REST framework tutorial

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, restful-authentication

I'm following the [Django REST framework tutorial (part 4)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) but I'm observing a discrepancy between the behavior of my API and what is expected according to the tutorial. Here is my project-level `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from snippets import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', views.UserList.as_view()),
    path('users/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
    path('', include('snippets.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

and here is the included `snippets.urls`:

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from snippets import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('snippets/', views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    path('snippets/<int:pk>/', views.SnippetDetail.as_view())
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

I've created a `permissions.py` with a custom permission class `IsOwnerOrReadOnly`:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

and I've added this class to `permission_classes` in the `SnippetDetail` class in `views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from snippets.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly


class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
```

However, when I make a POST request specifying only my credentials (using Httpie), I get a 400 Bad Request:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$ http -a kurtpeek:mypassword POST http://localhost:8000/snippets/ code="print 789"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 37
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 24 Jan 2018 18:13:47 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.4
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "owner": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Apparently, I need to specify `owner="1"` to get this to work:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:~ kurtpeek$ http -a kurtpeek:mypassword POST http://localhost:8000/snippets/ code="print 789" owner="1"
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 103
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 24 Jan 2018 18:13:35 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.4
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "code": "print 789",
    "id": 3,
    "language": "python",
    "linenos": false,
    "owner": 1,
    "style": "friendly",
    "title": ""
}
```

However, as I understand from the logic of the `has_object_permission` method of the `IsOwnerOrReadOnly` permissions class, the owner should be inferred from the `request.user`. This is also not how the example is given in the tutorial. Can anyone spot what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST request should go to your `SnippetList` view, not to `SnippetDetail`, so the custom permission class isn't used.

I don't know why you get this error, though. [According to the tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#updating-our-serializer), you should set `owner` to be a read-only field in `SnippetSerializer`.

```
owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how your serializer is defined/used, it isn't a permission issue. The field 'owner' needs to be set as read only or not required in the serializer.